# Sound system not working

Tags: windows-xp, audio, speakers

I've recently installed my new system.
But my sound is not working.

I'm on windows xp and I've logitec's Speaker System Z323

On my other os (windows server 2008) it's working fine, but on windows xp however it's not. There's no sound at all. So I looked at the device manager and the mulitimedia & sound system, and windows tells me that I've no audio device, so I've got no sound.

Does anyone know why I don't have sound? I've used windows xp on this computer in the past, it was working fine back then.

Please help me!

Checked the volume on the speakers & headset & software (there's no way however to turn the sound on because it's not there...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's missing a driver for the sound (either card, or on the motherboard)

Try searching for the MB manufacturer, and see if they offer drivers.

Comment: You but I see no sound card device in my device menager, so how can there be any driver for hardware windows doesn't see?

Comment: You were right, I did have drivers missing, I was almost sure that I had them all, although the answer was obvious it's also a vailid answer. Thank you

Comment: I've done exactly the same thing - sometimes you need to be reminded of the obvious :)